# How to access seam component that was created at the time the parameter value was set?

Tags: java, seam

My url has a parameter name=SSA-COLUMB.  The seam parameter (set in DevicesList.page.xml) is

```
<param name="name" value="#{searchDeviceName.paramValue}"/>
```

When I load the page the searchDeviceName component is instantiated and paramValue is set. I verified it with a print statement on setParamValue().  Here is the code for SearchDeviceName.java

```
@Name("searchDeviceName")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class SearchDeviceName {

    public String paramValue;
    public Table table;
    public String sqlString;
    public ArrayList<JoinClause> joinList;

    public SearchDeviceName() {
        Table devTable = new Table("devices","d","dev_id");
        setTable(devTable); 
        setSqlString(" d.name like '%"+paramValue+"%'");
    }

    <getters and setters>

}
```

I have a stateless session bean that grabs an instance of this component to use in building a sql statement.  But when I grab the component instance, it does not have paramValue set. Apparently it is a new instance of the component.

```
SearchDeviceName searchObj = (SearchDeviceName) Component.getInstance("searchDeviceName", ScopeType.CONVERSATION);
```

This is not the same instance of searchDeviceName that was instantiated when the parameter value got set.  I know this because paramValue is null rather than set to "SSA-COLUMB".

Is there any way to use in my session bean the same component intance that got created when the parameter value was set?  How do I grab it?

Here is the code that grabs the component

```
@Name("idListBuilder")
public class IdListBuilder {

    @In
    private Context conversationContext;

    @In(create = true)
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private String sqlQuery;
    private Table headTable;

    private ArrayList<String> restrictionValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Table> restrictionJoinTables  = new ArrayList<Table>();

    public IdListBuilder(Table table) {
        this.headTable = table;
        this.sqlQuery = "SELECT " + table.alias + "." + table.primaryKey + " FROM " +
                table.name + " " + table.alias;
        searchObjects.add("searchDeviceName");
        searchObjects.add("searchOfficeState");  
    }

    public List<Integer> getIdList(){
        evaluateSearchObjects();
        createQuery();
        /*
        Code for grabbing resultlist of query goes here.
        return resultList;
        */
        return null;
    }

    public void evaluateSearchObjects() {
            SearchDeviceName searchObj = (SearchDeviceName) Component.getInstance("searchDeviceName", ScopeType.CONVERSATION);
            if ( searchObj != null ) {
                restrictionValues.add(searchObj.sqlString);
                restrictionJoinTables.add(searchObj.table);
            }
    }

    void createQuery(){
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(sqlQuery);
        strBuilder.append(" where ");
        for ( String str : restrictionValues ){
            strBuilder.append(str);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the code for the @Stateless?

Comment: the @Stateless is not marked as such.  It is just business logic that saves no state.  Same thing? I have no idea.  Anyhow, I added the relevant code, edited for easy reading.

Comment: I'm just loading a single page.  I assume there is a temporary conversation that is begun, but it couldn't have closed already, right?

Comment: yep... everything seems to be in order, so there must be something else... I can't help you unless you post more code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but maybe contextual events are the way to go.

Take a look at this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5363)

Maybe you can listen to an event

```
   org.jboss.seam.preSetVariable.<name> // called when the context variable <name> is s et
   org.jboss.seam.postSetVariable.<name> // called when the context variable <name> is set


   @Observer("org.jboss.seam.postSetVariable.YOUR_COMPONENT")
   public void method() {
      //Maybe you need to retrieve the correct object as parameter also,look at the documentation
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that setParamValue() is being called *before* evaluateSearchObjects()?

What is invoking IdListBuilder.getIdList()? Perhaps that is occurring earlier in the JSF lifecycle that setParamValue().

Comment: hi. yes. confirmed. getIdList is invoked from getEjbql(), long after setParamValue() occurs.  I'm working on something else for the moment. May come back to this.